# AMFPHP 2.2 backoffice call simple works but call amf returns null?

Tags: php, mysql, amfphp

in back office when calling simple everything is fine all i have to do is fill in the appropriate field with a UID(userid) but when i use call AMF it returns null

```
<?php
```

class Gotoandlearn
    {
    public function __construct()
    {

```
    //mysql_connect("server", "username", "password");
    //mysql_select_db("database");
}

/**
 * Retrieves tutorial data
 * @returns title, description, and url
 */
function getTutorials($myId)
{

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "xxx";
    $password = "xxx";
    $dbname = "xxx";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "SELECT Name, Map FROM xxx WHERE Uid=$myId";
//  $sql = "SELECT Uid, Name, Map FROM xxx";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    // Check connection

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    return $result;






        } else {
            echo false;
        }
        $conn->close();



    //return mysql_query("SELECT title, description, url FROM Tutorials");
    }
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

With Amfphp you can't return a resource. Best practice is to use PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php which returns an object or an array that be can be sent back.

You can see some sample code here https://github.com/silexlabs/amfphp-2.0/blob/master/Examples/Php/ExampleServices/UserService.php

Comment: after ignoring that it didnt work returning anything with with the call amf i wen ahead and tested in flash builder pure as3 code in my game and it worked anyway. but it ended up lagginng my host "hostgator" and returning 505 so often i drop it completely..thank you for your response

Comment: the 505 error was caused by cloudlflare..i dropped the entire project and moved onto unity for a game engine instead of flash...rainbows and unicorns everywhere...so happy i moved to unity